# Фильтрация маркеров в prunecluster

Tags: javascript, filter, leafletjs

Загружаю маркеры на карту. Как правильно их отфильтровывать? Пробовал удалить все маркеры через функцию RemoveMarkers(), но они все равно остаются просто не отрисовываются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал данные методы

```
leafletView.RemoveMarkers();
leafletView.Cluster._markers = [];
leafletView.ProcessView();
```

где

```
var leafletView = new PruneClusterForLeaflet();
```